# как навсегда прописать путь в $PATH на mac

Tags: консоль, macos, path

Нужно прописать папку в path, но стандарт из интернета не работает. Путь скопирован через option  и пкм.

```
 echo $PATH
```

выдает

```
/opt/local/bin:...:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

через

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

добавил в конец

```
$export PATH=$PATH:/Users/Desktop/test
```

сохранил, проверил опять эхом ничего не поменялось, открыл новое окно терминала- не поменялось.
Тогда прописал туда

```
$export PATH=/Users/Desktop/test:$PATH
```

также прописал в ~/.bashrc, тоже не поменялась.
Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Начиная с macOS 10.15 основным шеллом для macOS идёт zsh, а не bash.

Поэтому прописывать изменения PATH нужно в .zshrc (или другом подходящем для zsh файле).